# How to unit test this converter?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, wpf

I am beginning with unit testing in c#.

Here is my converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    int c = 0;
    if (value != null)
    {
        var path = value.ToString();

        for (int x = 0; x < path.Length; x++)
        {
            if (c == 2) { return path.Substring(x).Replace("%","/"); }
            if (path[x] == '%') c++;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Here, if I pass a string "TestString" or any string without %, its going to return me the same string, right?
What should I pass as value?

Comment: What is the expected behavior of this method? That's what you should test.

Comment: Why have you got the parameters, `Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture`? None of them are used. Also, don't use `object`; change the method to `public T Convert<T>(T value) ...`. And finally give it a meaningful name. What does it convert?

Comment: @DavidArno, this is implementing an interface that is part of C# for UI work.  The parameters that are not used can be ignored.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch, oh, that is horrible. Just looked up how they are used in WPF. That is nasty :(

Comment: That it is.  As much as possible, I try to stay away from converters and put logic like this in a ViewModel.  However, sometimes you can't get away from them (like boolean to enum conversions for toggling visibility or implementing radio buttons).  Again, ugly.

Answer (score 2):

You've got three main things to test:

- Passing in a null value
- Passing in strings that don't get mangled
- Passing in strings that do get mangled, making sure they are mangled correctly

Beyond that, you might want to check if your logic breaks with an empty string.  NOTE: it looks like this is only supposed to replace all instances of `%` with `/` if there are exactly 2.  The question is whether there are further rules that need defining.

Answer (score 2):

### Semantic analysis

- I have no idea what is the intention this method.
- The names of the method and parameters are not helping. *It converts... something*.
- I do not have access to the requirements for this method.
- The use of the type `object` is not helping.

I would argue that the use of `object` is bad design. Instead, I would use `string` for `value` and make calling `.ToString` responsibility of the caller. Static analysis will then tell you that the return value of the method can be `string` too.

I see [Berin Loritsch comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/371728/how-to-unit-test-this-converter#comment815719_371728) saying that this method signature is required by some third party system (namely WPF). Well, *Shame on them.* Consider extracting your method, and giving it the proper types.

---

### Unit tests

It is correct that you should be testing your requirements. Yet, the lack of them does not mean we cannot consider some scenarios to test. However, since we are not sure what the expected behavior is, we cannot be sure of the pass criteria for the tests. If you do not know either, I guess you will figure out after you consider each case (or perhaps when you run the code).

So, let us see some scenarios. Consider, what is the effective interface of `value`:

- It can be `null`, so, test passing `null`.
- We will call `ToString` on it. *Aha!*

  Pass an object that when you call `.ToString` on it...

  - Throws an exception.
  - Returns null.
  - Returns an empty string.
  - Returns some string.
- It will call `Substring` on the result, and then `Replace("%","/")`. We also see a check for two, so let us go - at least - up to three.

  Pass an object that when you call `.ToString` on it...

  - returns a string that contains a single "%"
  - returns a string that contains a couple "%"
  - returns a string that contains three "%"

**Notes**:

- You may want to return strings of different lengths.
- Those strings may contain other things aside from "%".

As far as unit-testing string based methods go, you may also want to test strings that have eastern symbols, emoji, surrogate pairs, composite characters, zero width space, and left-to-right and right-to-left marks. However, if you find anything wrong here, it is most likely a bug in .NET.

With the requirements, there could be more tests to do. In addition, as you see the results and improve the code, there could be regression tests or tests designed to increase the coverage.

---

### Static analysis

Tests are not a replacement of static analysis. And any static analysis tool will tell you that you are not using `targetType`, `parameter` and `culture`.

I suppose this is a sad accepted fact, and that anybody working with this system will figure out soon enough. However, I will still tell you to consider adding a comment for the lack of use of these parameters. That will ease readability, in particular for people not familiar with the system (like me).